# How to refer to another collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I go about making a manual reference in MongoDB and so that I can set the "owner" index in my item collection to the name of a person in my "person collection". Right now I have

```
var obj = db.collection(PERSON_COLLECTION).findOne({"name": req.body.owner} );
```

But how can I extract the name and _Id from the selected document so I can set it to Item's owner field.

```
//Schema for Item Model - DB Name 'Items'
{
    "item_name": <String>,
    "category": <String>,
    "price": <Number>,
    "Owner": <String>,
    "Quantity": <Number>,
    "Transaction": <TransactionSchema> -- Optional
}
//Schema for Person Model

{
    "_id": <ObjectId>
    "name": <String>,
    "email_address": <String>,
    "location": <String>,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
db.collection(PERSON_COLLECTION).findOne({"name": req.body.owner}, function(err,doc) {})
```

to extract the fields you'd like and then you can refer to it using dot notation such as doc.name